# How to fix the position of map in QGIS after save the file and don't change any colors in selected feauture polygons?

Tags: qgis, geojson

First I have opened a GeoJSON file in QGIS, gives the Labels name, the map is for the Aurangabad district (of India), and there are eight talukas.

I want to display the four talukas that are growing a bajra crop. So I have coloured the four talukas and using "Text Annotation" I have put some information for the four talukas.

Now, I am doing screen shot for that map, otherwise it map is go down, go up, Zoom in , Zoom out automatically and my title:  "Crop: Bajra"  was not accurate in the top.  So I need to take a screen shot, for displaying bajra crop grow for four talukas.

Please see the screen shot images...
(yellow four talukas image file)

[image]

So, when I save this map file, and open it in QGIS it will not show "yellow" colour for selected 4 talukas, same colour shows for all eight talukas and I need to set the position of map again.

[image]

So, my question is:

1. I  want to first fix the map position  at the middle, so map will be not zoom in, zoom out, go left, go right, fix at the position, so I can give the title at the top of the map "Crop: Bajra".
2. Using "Text Annotation" I will put my information for selected four talukas. And colour it for four talukas.

And once I save that file, that will not change any colour and not need to set map at the middle. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are confused of displaying data for analysis purpose and displaying data for layout (cartographic/printing) purpose. You should use the composer to do what you want.

You are getting the yellow color in the map and disappeared in the layout because you are using selection tool which turns the polygon to yellow, which will not appear in the layout. To style the polygon layer with 2 colors green and yellow, go to the polygon layer in the table of content -> `Layer properties -> Style -> Select Rule-based Styling`

[image]

- Double click the "no filter" and enter the following expression
  `"Field_name" = 'name 1' OR "Field_name" = 'name 2' OR "Field_name" =
  'name 3' OR "Field_name" = 'name 4'` where *Field_name* is the name
  of the field that contains the names of the polygon and name 1, name
  2, name 3, and name 4 are the names inside the yellow polygons,
  respectively. Give them yellow color.
- Add another rule and double click as before and write `ELSE` and give it a green color.

[image]

You will get two color polygons:

[image]

- To create map in the composer, check the following tutorial: [Making a Map](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html)

Comment: yes sir very confuse, can you please tell me how can I set the map at the middle? and save as a image file so no need to go down map, no need to zoom etc ? , when I save as image then yellow color will be removed .

Comment: complete map display at the middle, so how can i set the map ?

Comment: awesome tutorial .you are provide, thanks you very much, totally understand how to save image and adjust etc...

Comment: @KiranPrajapati Good luck.